# Homegraph in google smart home skill

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I developed a smart home skill for my company, I did it without using HomeGraph as final user don't care about that they just want a couple of easy traits implemented in devices. Is it required to use Homegraph in order to pass Home suit test and get the certification request accepted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue to develop your project and test it on your account, but in order to successfully submit for review, you need to abide by [several certification policies](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies#smart-enabled_devices):

- > All devices are expected to report state updates to Google through the HomeGraph API’s Report State, with the exception of command-only devices like IR controllers.
- > Developers shall report device configuration updates in your ecosystem to Google; ... This can be accomplished through the Request Sync API.

To summarize, you will need to integrate the HomeGraph APIs and pass the test suite in order to be ready for certification.

Comment: Amazing Nick, thanks for helping me out!. Let me ask you one last thing, I've been following nodejs example you have in github, but I am not sure wether using Cloud Firestore database is required or is just an example (firestore.ts) and I can implement that on mongoDB. Thanks!

Comment: It's just an example of a database. You can use MongoDB for data and another server instead of App Engine. You have full control over how your webhook/backend is implemented.